# How to implement input without enter in C++ console game

Tags: c++, input, console

I am stuck with the input with no enter input. 
I tried to use kbhit() + getch() from conio.h and it doesn't work on my system (Win10 and Ubuntu - unistd.h and termios.h). Program just skips block with these functions.
Then I used GetAsynkKeyState from windows.h. It works in the game (Level) though buggy, but doesn't in a Menu. Program as well skips (or something) block with input dispatch.
Menu input:

```
// The menu interface
bool Menu::SelectLevel() {
    cout << "Select the level:" << endl;
    size_t arrow_pos = 0;
    // Prints level's names and char to exit the game
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= _levels.size(); ++i) {
        // Draw arrow before selected level
        if (i == arrow_pos) {
            cout << '>' << i + 1 << " - " << _levels[i].first[0] << endl;;
        }
        // Draw arrow before the exit select
        else if (i == _levels.size() && i == arrow_pos) {
            cout << '>' << "Exit" << endl;
        }
        // Draw the exit option
        else if (i == _levels.size()) {
            cout << ' ' << "Exit" << arrow_pos << endl;
        }
        // Draw levels list
        else {
            cout << ' ' << i + 1 << " - " << _levels[i].first[0] << endl;
        }
    }
    // Input from keyboard TODO DOESN'T WORK!:
    // If 's' pressed move arrow down
    PoollingDelay(1);
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x53) & 0x8000) {
        ++arrow_pos;
        // If arrow reached top it goes to the bottom
        if (arrow_pos == _levels.size() + 1) {
            arrow_pos = 0;
        }
    }
    // If 'w' pressed move arrow up
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x57) & 0x8000) {
        --arrow_pos;
        // If arrow reached bottom it goes to the top
        if (arrow_pos == 65535) {
            arrow_pos = _levels.size() + 1;
        }
    }
    // If Return pressed
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000) {
        // Don't think it would be worthy
        if (arrow_pos < 1 || arrow_pos > _levels.size() - 1) {
            throw runtime_error("Wrong select: " + to_string(arrow_pos));
        }
        // If player tired of this shit
        if (arrow_pos == _levels.size() - 1) {
            ClearTerminal();
            return false;
        }
        // Play
        PlayLevel(arrow_pos);
    }
    ClearTerminal();
    return true;
}
```

Level input:

```
// TO DO DOESN'T WORK!:
void Level::ReadCommand() {
    PoollingDelay(100);
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x57)) {
        Move(_NORTH);
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x41)) {
        Move(_WEST);
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x53)) {
        Move(_SOUTH);
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x44)) {
        Move(_EAST);
    }
    else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x45)) {
        throw runtime_error(exit_the_lvl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code in the question please ([edit]). Links to code stored elsewhere aren't acceptable.

Comment: I guess it's impossible to do it in console game, but I'm not 100% sure about that

Comment: @EdinHajdarevic I found a couple examples on Stackoverflow and gitHub where were implemented that feathure. But on my system these examples don't work..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, it may and may not work. It is possible in OOP, but I don't know about Console Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't using only C++ and its standard library.

This is because the language is not designed to handle low-level hardware events. To do this, you need to rely on a separate library, dedicated to handle I/O. Lots of them, some are more or less easy to integrate. For simple games, [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) is nice.